# C++ cin is used in while loop but console screen is not held

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am using cin as condition for while loop where it accepts an integer unless an end of file or a character is entered. But the console window disappears just after the result. How can I hold the screen

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    int num = 0, sum = 0;

    while (cin >> num) {
        sum += num;
    }


    cout << "Sum is: "
        << sum
        << endl;

    cout << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe, what you mean with hold?

Comment: The problem here is that the newline which is entered after each number is left in the input buffer, to be read by the `cin.get()` call. Or if you give some non-numeric input, *all* of that will be left to be read by next input operation.

Comment: This I learned recently, that the buffer held by std::cin has to be empty if you want it to hold your program. cin.get() will extract the next character from its stream buffer and then continue. The only reason it will hold or pause your program is if it's empty, and in that case it awaits input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.get()` will consume the new line character, which is left in the input stream from the last number that you committed with "enter". Hence, the next `cin.get()`, from which you expect to wait until the next user input before output console disappears, will not wait for additional input but will return immediately.

To solve the problem, you could ignore (cf. [cppreference/ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)) anything until (and including) the next new line in the buffer before reading in the next item:

```
int main() {
    int a;

    cin >> a;

    // do something with a, write to console, ...

    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');        
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: This is not working, instead is used cin.clear() cin.ignore() cin.get(). These three functions when written in a code seems to work but i am not able to understand the working. Can you explain to me how this works